# For loop is running after I navigate out of the View in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, xcode, for-loop, swiftui

I'm calling `populateArray()` on `task`. The problem is that the for loop on `populateArray()` continues after I navigate out of the `View`. How can I stop this for loop from continuing?

```
final class EmojisGridViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var emojisImageArray: [UIImage] = []
    private var originalEmojisImageArray: [UIImage] = []
    private let imageManager: ImageManager
    private let coreDataManager: CoreDataManager

    init(imageManager: ImageManager = ImageManager(),
         coreDataManager: CoreDataManager = CoreDataManager.shared) {
        
        self.imageManager = imageManager
        self.coreDataManager = coreDataManager
    }
    
    func populateArray() async {
        for urlString in coreDataManager.emojisDictionary.values {
            if let url = URL(string: urlString),
               let image = await imageManager.downloadAsyncAwait(url, type: .emoji) {
                    await MainActor.run {
                        emojisImageArray.append(image)
                        originalEmojisImageArray.append(image)
                    }
                }
        }
        
        originalEmojisImageArray = emojisImageArray
    }
}

struct EmojisGridView: View {

    @StateObject var viewModel = EmojisGridViewModel()
    private let columns = [GridItem(.adaptive(minimum: 80))]
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ScrollView {
                LazyVGrid(columns: columns, spacing: 20) {
                    ForEach(viewModel.emojisImageArray, id:\.self) { image in
                                Image(uiImage: image)
                    }
                }
                .padding(.horizontal)
            }
        }
        .task {
            await viewModel.populateArray()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The view cancels the task but you are calling subtasks inside and should check for the cancelation. Otherwise, they continue:

```
if let url = URL(string: urlString),
   let image = await imageManager.downloadAsyncAwait(url, type: .emoji) {
    guard !Task.isCancelled else { return } //  Like this
    await MainActor.run {
        emojisImageArray.append(image)
        originalEmojisImageArray.append(image)
    }
}
```

<sub>You can also return the task to make it cancel automatically</sub>