# Cancel running task

Tags: swift, async-await

We have a requirement where we want to cancel a running task once we have switched between Tabs, I was looking at various different post regarding  same, but I was not able to get a clear picture on how cancellation works.

Scenario:

Let's say I have an application with tab bar having 2 views (**View A** and **View B**). When I switch to View B I will invoke around 2 API calls, but at same time if user switches to View A I would like to cancel all 2 API calls. I want to control this because user is freely allow to switch between tabs whenever they want, so let's say if they switch 8-9 times just for testing purpose, we will invoke those 2 API calls 8-9 times and previous calls are still in progress.

**Code Example:**

```
class View2ViewModel{
    let apiService:APIService

    init(apiService:APIService){
        self.apiService = apiService
        executeTask()
    }

    func executeTask(){
        Task {
            do{
                let firstResult = try await apiService.getTestData(for: "First test url")
                // Second depends on first
                let secondResult = try await apiService.getTestData1(for: "Second test url", with: firstResult)
            }catch{
                print("error")
            }
        }
    }
}

class APIService{
    let networkManager:NetworkManager

    init(networkManager:NetworkManager){
        self.networkManager = networkManager
    }

    func getTestData(for Url:String) async throws -> [String] {
        guard let url = URL(string: Url) else{
            return []
        }
        let data =  try await networkManager.performDataTaskAsync(with:URLRequest(url:url))
        return try JSONDecoder().decode([String].self,from:data)
    }

    func getTestData1(for Url:String,with requestData:[String]) async throws -> [String] {
        guard let url = URL(string: Url) else{
            return []
        }
        // let's assume i crated a URLRequest with requestData
        let data =  try await networkManager.performDataTaskAsync(with:URLRequest(url:url))
        return try JSONDecoder().decode([String].self,from:data)
    }
}

class NetworkManager{
    enum NetworkError:Error{
        case connectivity
    }
    public func performDataTaskAsync(with request:URLRequest) async throws -> Data {
        // Use the async variant of URLSession to fetch data
        // Code might suspend here
        let successResponseRange = (200...299)
        let (data, response) = try await URLSession.shared.data(for: request)
        if let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse,
           !successResponseRange.contains(response.statusCode) {
            if let logs = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
                APILogs.logsText.append("\n\(logs)")
            }
            throw NetworkError.connectivity
        }
        return data
    }
}
```

In above code example, `View2ViewModel` is initialised every time we switch to second tab and let's say deinitialised when we switch back to `Tab 1`. Now let's say I switched to `Tab 2` and API call is invoked, then quickly switched to Tab 1, and did this process *8-9* times, so multiple call will become active at one point of time? Or if object is deallocated will `Task` also be cancelled (Not sure about this as I read task will keep strong reference unitl it receives result).

In summary I only want one API call active when I'm on View 2 and cancel any other running task. What's the best and better way of doing this?

I have seen `Task.Cancellation()`  can be used to explicitly invoke cancellation, but I'm not understanding how is it useful in my case? Also if I want to invoke **task.cancel()** where should I fit that line in my code?

Comment: Using view models in SwiftUI is something of an anti pattern. Have a model object that lives longer than a single view instance. Then it can know whether it needs to actually fetch data or not, but to answer your question you need to explicitly check if your task has been cancelled after you get the first result and before you get the second result. You could cancel the task in the `onDisappear` of your view.

Comment: You won't be able to cancel the first api call because it is going to start as soon as the view is displayed.

Comment: Get rid of those floating Task in the VM and use .task or task(id: selectedTab)

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77459569/for-loop-is-running-after-i-navigate-out-of-the-view-in-swiftui) might be of some help.

Comment: “Using view models in SwiftUI is something of an anti pattern.” … No, MVVM is a perfectly viable pattern in SwiftUI. If anything, SwiftUI finally provides the missing mechanism to bind views with model objects, an essential aspect of MVVM (something that was always kludgy in UIKit/AppKit). Use MVVM or don’t use it; it’s up to you. There are strongly held positions on both sides of the issue. But the question of adopting MVVM (or not) is immaterial to the question of cancelation, anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two basic cancelation patterns:

1. Use SwiftUI [`.task`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/task(priority:_:)/) view modifier to enjoy automatic task cancelation. As the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/task(priority:_:)/) say:

   > If the task doesn’t finish before SwiftUI removes the view or the view changes identity, SwiftUI cancels the task.

   So, consider:

   ```swift
   struct FirstView: View {
       var body: some View {
           VStack {
               …
           }
           .task {
               do {
                   try await fetch()
               } catch {
                   print(error)
               }
           }
       }

       func fetch() async throws { … }
   }
   ```

   So, if this is one of your tabs, as soon as you leave the tab, the `.task` will be canceled. Thus `fetch` will be canceled, too (assuming it supports cancelation; more on that later).

   So, I launched my app, went from tab 1, to 2, to 3, back to 2, back to 3, and finally back to 1. I created Instruments’ “Points of Interest” intervals associated with the fetch async method associated with each of the three views. I also posted Ⓢ signpost where the asynchronous tasks were canceled and cut short, yielding:

   [image]

   Each time I jumped to a tab, it launched a five-second asynchronous task, and each time I left that tab to go to another, it canceled that asynchronous task before it finished (ending the interval above, adding the Ⓢ signpost). Because I was jumping between them so quickly, only pausing at the very end, only that last task on tab 1 finished without being canceled (a full five seconds, no Ⓢ signpost). (This is an exaggerated example, but it illustrates the idea.) For most use-cases, this is the best approach in SwiftUI.

2. Save `Task` to cancel it later.

   ```swift
   let task = Task {
       do {
           try await fetch()
       } catch {
           print(error)
       }
   }
   ```

   And now that you have that `Task` reference, you can then later:

   ```swift
   task.cancel()
   ```

   So, you could do something like:

   ```swift
   struct FirstView: View {
       @State var task: Task<Void, Error>?

       var body: some View {
           VStack {
               …
           }
           .task {
               task?.cancel() // cancel the prior task, if any (and if still in progress)
               task = Task {
                   try await fetch()
               }
           }
       }

       func fetch() async throws {…}
   }
   ```

   Yielding:

   [image]

   In this case, (with the same sequence of jumping between tabs), the first task for tab 2 was canceled because I revisited tab 2 before the first async task for that tab finished. The same is true with tab 3. But the first task for tab 1 (as I was jumping between tabs 2 and 3) had a chance to finish although I had moved on to different tabs. Likewise, when I jumped back to the first tab at the end of this sequence, the last running async task for tabs 2 and 3 had a chance to finish, as well.

   This pattern is useful if the fetch requests are not just updating the UI, but perhaps also caching results or doing something useful that is important beyond the lifetime of the view. It is a less common pattern, a bit of an edge case, and is little more complicated and takes up more system resources. So, I would only consider this pattern if you really needed this behavior (i.e., if the async task was really doing something other than just fetching data for the current view).

So, the question is whether you want to cancel the request as soon as you leave the tab (in which case, the first pattern easiest) or whether you you want to avoid a backlog of requests (in which case, the second pattern is best).

Personally, I generally use option 1, but I have used option 2 in those cases where the asynchronous method is doing something more than just updating the UI.

---

Implicit in the above examples is that the method you call actually supports cancelation. Consider your example:

```swift
func executeTask() {
    Task {
        do {
            let firstResult = try await apiService.getTestData(for: "First test url")
            // Second depends on first
            let secondResult = try await apiService.getTestData1(for: "Second test url", with: firstResult)
        } catch {
            print(error)   // note, it is probably more useful to print the actual error, like here, not just the string “error”, as in the original code snippet
        }
    }
}
```

That is not cancelable (by the caller, at least). You are creating a `Task` (unstructured concurrency), but not saving it anywhere. Probably easiest is to make it an `async` function. That is now cancelable (via either of the two mechanisms outlined above. For example:

```swift
func executeTask() async throws {
    do {
        let firstResult = try await apiService.getTestData(for: "First test url")
        // Second depends on first
        let secondResult = try await apiService.getTestData1(for: "Second test url", with: firstResult)
    } catch {
        print(error)   // fine, print the error for diagnostic purposes …
        throw error    // … but probably rethrow the error so the caller knows what happened
    }
}
```

Or, more simply:

```swift
func executeTask() async throws {
    let firstResult = try await apiService.getTestData(for: "First test url")
    // Second depends on first
    let secondResult = try await apiService.getTestData1(for: "Second test url", with: firstResult)
}
```

Bottom line, be wary of introducing unnecessary [unstructured concurrency](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/documentation/the-swift-programming-language/concurrency#Unstructured-Concurrency). Sure, when bridging from a synchronous context to an asynchronous context, we have to use `Task`, but we would do that at the earliest opportunity, not burying it inside the view model. And if you use the `.task` view modifier, introducing unstructured concurrency is entirely unnecessary. And in those extremely unusual situations where we need to introduce unstructured concurrency from within an asynchronous context, we would add our own cancelation logic. Remaining within structured concurrency keeps things simple.

Answer (score 2):

In SwiftUI, async/await is `.task` not `Task { }` and background work can simply be cancelled by changing the `id` param, e.g.

```
@State var isRunning = false
@Environment(\.networkController) var controller

...

Button(isRunning ? "Cancel" : "Start") {
    isRunning.toggle()
}
.task(id: isRunning) {
    if !isRunning {
       return // happens the first time the view appears and also when a fetch ends.
    }
    do {
        results = await controller.fetch()
    }
    catch {
        // cancelled
    }
    isRunning = false
}
```

The reason we use an `EnvironmentKey` for the controller is so it can be mocked in Previews.